# Very slow queries in a large database even with indexes

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, query-optimization, database-optimization

I have a large database with `login` and `level` columns. All queries were slow before I created indexes on these columns:

```
CREATE INDEX users_login_index on users(login);
CREATE INDEX users_level_index on users(level);
```

Now I can quickly find a user by `login` (it's unique) or many users by `level`. This query is fast:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='somelogin123';
```

But this query is *very* slow:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='somelogin123' AND level=1;
```

Why the query becomes slow after adding an additional condition which is also indexed? How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite might be choosing the wrong index.  I suspect that `level` has only a small number of values.  That is usually not a good idea for an index.  Try making that a composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX users_level_index_login on users(level, login);
```